# mathabx package and Maya symbols problem

Tags: symbols

I'm desperately trying to use the Mayan math symbols I found listed in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List.  The document says that these symbols can be used this way (page 65):

```
Table 200:
mathabx
Mayan Digits
0  \maya{0}
1  \maya{1}
2  \maya{2}
3  \maya{3}
4  \maya{4}
5  \maya{5}
```

I've added `\usepackage{mathabx}` at the top of my document and tried using as a test `\maya{3}` and then `$\maya{3}$` in my document but get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\maya ...mayacnter =#1 \setbox 0\hbox {\mathbfont 
                                                  0}\mayawidth =\wd 0 \left ...
l.91 $\maya{3}
              $
?
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm not able to find any example documents online showing how to use this correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One has to provide an appropriate definition for `\mathbfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}

\begin{document}

$\maya{0}\qquad\maya{3}$

$\mayadigit{0}\qquad\mayadigit{23}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the need to define the `\mathbfont` a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Kaba: It is a bug, but it has been corrected in the version on the homepage http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~phan/metafont.html#mathabx but the author hasn't uploaded the fix to ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, this is also what the author told me; forgot to follow up here.