# Mayan symbols and mathabx package

Tags: fonts, mathabx

I am trying to typeset Mayan numerals using the mathabx package as in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125983/mathabx-package-and-maya-symbols-problem)!. More specifically, I compile the following segment of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}
\begin{document}
$\maya{0}\qquad\maya{3}$
$\mayadigit{0}\qquad\mayadigit{23}$
\end{document}
```

But I got the following error message:

`Font U/matha/m/n/10=matha10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`

What I am missing? I am using Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found

Comment: @TheExplosiveSheep Well, possibly it is the same problem but we can't really tell unless the OP confirms it, can we? That is, I agree that you are almost certainly right by 'Answered here' seems a bit bald.